# Why can I ping a server, but nmap normal scan cannot see the host?

Tags: network, nmap, network-scanners

I am able to ping a server on an vpn. However, when I use a normal nmap scan it does not pickup on the host. Doing a scan with host discovery turned off (`nmap -Pn host` scan) does show the host.

If I am not mistaken, should my ping not fail if the regular nmap scan (`nmap host`) fails?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [nmap.org](https://nmap.org/book/man-host-discovery.html):

> If no host discovery options are given, Nmap sends an ICMP echo
> request, a TCP SYN packet to port 443, a TCP ACK packet to port 80,
> and an ICMP timestamp request. ... For unprivileged
> Unix shell users, the default probes are a SYN packet to ports 80 and
> 443 using the connect system call.

I am guessing you ran `nmap` as an unprivileged user, so ICMP was not used for host discovery. Using `-Pn` "works" because it skips host discovery and treats the host as up no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

The ping protocol is a layer 3 protocol, so, it doesn't made any TCP/UDP connection and it doesn't use any port, maybe the server that you ran nmap against it is simply block TCP/UDP connection or Block them just if they come from unknown IP.

Comment: Either TCP/UDP and ICMP (the protocol used by ping) is layer 3. This answer is incorrect.

Comment: @slayer ICMP is often presented as a layer 3 protocol (which I do disagree with)

Comment: @slayer, TCP/UDP are transport layer protocols but the ICMP is a network layer protocol.

Comment: @MohamedMarrouchi The TCP/UDP on transport (4) layer doesn’t provide a guarantee of packet delivery. It is the charge of the network (3) layer to assurance the connection-oriented and connectionless service, AFAIK. The ICMP is a connectionless protocol.

Comment: @MohamedMarrouchi Ah! I noticed a mess here. Now I understood what you mean. When you affirmed, ICMP protocol is the network layer to clarify that it is a connectionless protocol, I had confused because TCP/UDP  is also layer 3. So, I had understood that you were dealing with TCP/UDP working only at the transport layer. Your answer was confusing to me, but now that I understand, I agree. lol